# VisualStudio 2012 Running PSEXEC from webapplication error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

When I try to run PSEXEC from visualstudio 2012 Webforms application. I get below error:-
StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.

I have some very basic questions to understand:-

1. When I run the webapplication it runs on localhost:2322/default.aspx. So does the localhost runs on "DefaultAppPool" by default?
2. The ApplicationPoolIdentity is running on built-in account "ApplicationPoolIdentity" I tried changing it to "Local System" and "Network Service" in IIS 7.5 but still throws the above error.

Below is my code:-

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                FileName = @"E:\PSTools\PSExec.exe",
                Arguments = @"\\machineA -u domain\username -p passwrd c:\Installer.exe"
            };

            Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string errormessage = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you need to add 'RedirectStandardOutput = true'.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.That resolved that error. But I am getting remote server connection issue. How can I get user account/credentials on which process.start is running under programmatically in c#?